Algoritmos y Estructuras de Datos (en OmegaUp) Ordenamiento
Tengo la duda al enviar mi programa en la plataforma de OmegaUp la misma plataforma me dice que mi salida es incorrecta, pero he ejecutado el código en el mismo compilador de la plataforma "OmegaUp" y me aparece una palomita 1/1 statement_001 lo que dice que es correcto con los datos simulados. Entonces mi pregunta es cual podría ser el error ?
Adjunto el ejercicio con las restricciones que me da OmegaUp
"Límite de memoria  32 MiB, Límite de tiempo (caso) 1s, Límite de tiempo (total)    1m0s, Entrada/Salida    Consola,    Tamaño límite de entrada (bytes)    10 KiB"

Código:
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    int N, R;
    cin >> N >> R;
    priority_queue<double> pq;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        int x, y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        double distancia = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        pq.push(distancia);
    }

    while (pq.size() > R) {
        pq.pop();
    }

    double distancia_total = 0;
    while (!pq.empty()) {
        distancia_total += pq.top() * 2;
        pq.pop();
    }

    cout << round(distancia_total) << "\n";
    return 0;
}


Entiendo que para verificar que el programa está bien, compara la salida del mismo con la salida esperada. Así que un carácter de más seria suficiente para que falle. Prueba quitando el salto de línea que imprimes después del número.

No entiendo por qué la salida es 16 si la suma de las tres distancias mínimas ([2,1], [2,2], [1,3}) es 8'21.

El código es en esencia correcto, pero falla por un detalle bastante poco intuitivo a simple vista. Todo es correcto hasta que llega la hora de mostrar el resultado:
cout << round(distancia_total) << "\n";

Dos detalles:

std::round efectivamente redondea al entero más cercano pero retorna el resultado como un double (en este caso).

std::cout al mostrar los valores de coma flotante usará la configuración de salida por defecto. Por ejemplo:

Los valores de coma flotante grandes se mostrarán en notación científica o exponencial:
 std::cout <<  16777217.0 << "\n";  // 1.67772e+07


Los valores que representen enteros no muestran la parte decimal:
 std::cout << 1216.0 << "\n";  // 1216





Esto hace que std::cout << std::round(16.21); muestre "16" pero     std::cout << std::round(1652331.21); muestre "1.65233e+06".
Cierto es que el ejercicio no lo deja totalmente claro:

El valor de D (redondeado al entero más cercano).

pero el problema es que espera que "1652331.21" termine como "1652331" y no como "1.65233e+06".
Puedes cambiar el formato con el que std::cout mostrara el número, por ejemplo:
#include <iomanip>

std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0) << std::round(distancia_total);

o puedes usar std::lround() que retorna un long directamente, en vez de std::round():
std::cout << std::lround(distancia_total);

